# Unit step function into geometric series

Tags: linear-algebra, laplace-transform, geometric-series

The unit staircase function is defined as follows:
$f(t)=n$ if $n-1 \le t < n$ for $n \in \{1,2,3, \ldots\}$.

> How do you show that $\displaystyle f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty u(t-k)$?

Comment: How is $u$ defined?

Comment: u is just a function of t @ViktorGlombik